# AutoMapper: Ignore specific dictionary item(s) during mapping

Tags: c#, enums, automapper

**Context:**

There 2 main classes that look something like this:

```
public class Source
{
   public Dictionary<AttributeType, object> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Target
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

And the sub / collection / Enum types:

```
public class Attribute
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}

public enum AttributeType
{
    Title,
    Description,
    SomethingElse,
    Foobar
}
```

Currently my Map looks like this:

```
 CreateMap<Source, Target>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapAttribute(AttributeType.Description))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opt => opt.MapAttribute(AttributeType.Title));
```

Where `MapAttribute` gets the item from the `Dictionary` and using the `AttributeType` I've provided, adds it to the target collection as a (name & value) object (using a try get and returning an empty if the key does not exist)...

After all of this my Target set end's up looking like this:

```
{ 
  title: "Foo", 
  attributes: [
     { name: "SomethingElse", value: "Bar" }, 
     { name: "Title", value: "Foo"}
  ] 
}
```

---

**Question:**

How do I go about mapping the rest of the items to the target class, but I need to be able to exclude specific keys (like, title or description). E.G. Source.Attribute items that have a defined place in target gets excluded from the Target.Attributes collection, and "left-over" properties still go to Target.Attributes.

For even more clarity (if my source looks like this):

```
{ attributes: { title: "Foo", somethingelse: "Bar" } }
```

it would map to a target like this:

```
{ title: "Foo", attributes: [{ name: "SomethingElse", value: "Bar" }] }
```

---

I've attempted this, but it does not compile, stating the following:

> Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.

```
CreateMap<KeyValuePair<AttributeType, object>, Attribute>()
   .ForSourceMember(x => x.Key == AttributeType.CompanyName, y => y.Ignore())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to prefilter values on the mapping configuration, that some values would even not go to the target 
I'm using automapper **v6.1.1**, there are some difference, but the idea should be the same)

To make things works I have to add `KeyValuePair<AttributeType, object>` to `Attribute` mapping first (`MapAttribute` just returns dictionary value)

```
CreateMap<KeyValuePair<AttributeType, object>, Attribute>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Key))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Value));
```

As it's defined which attributes should be ignored, they will goes to ignore list, based on which mapping will filter out excess attributes

```
var ignoreAttributes = new[] {AttributeType.Description, AttributeType.Title};
CreateMap<Source, Target>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.MapAttribute(AttributeType.Description)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.MapAttribute(AttributeType.Title)))
    .ForMember(dest=>dest.Attributes, opt=> opt.MapFrom(s=>s.Attributes
        .Where(x=> !ignoreAttributes.Contains(x.Key))));
```

Based on the final mapping example

```
var result = Mapper.Map<Target>(new Source
{
    Attributes = new Dictionary<AttributeType, object>
    {
        {AttributeType.Description, "Description"},
        {AttributeType.Title, "Title"},
        {AttributeType.SomethingElse, "Other"},
    }
});
```

result will have filled Titel, Description and just one attribute SomethingElse

[image]
[image]